# Wait function in Event

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

I am facing an issue to use wait function in event block.

My code goes like this :

if (condition)

{

Wait.free(agent);

}

It throws an error that "agent is not variable:
PS: Wait is the block used in my required trajectory and I want to free the first agent that was in the wait queue whenever a particular condition is satisfied

Answer (score 1):

the way to do it is this:

```
if(condition){
     if(wait.size()>0){
          wait.free(wait.get(0));
     }
}
```

you don't have access to the agent when you are using an event block...

Comment: Great answer Felipe

Comment: Thank you so very much. It was such a relief. This is working perfectly. :D